# How to detect a forced update

Tags: git

When a branch history is changed on the remote, you typically get

```
o git@git.server.com:XXXXX/Project.git
 + efe2e8b...cda0ee7 HEAD -> Ant_Config_processing (forced update)
```

Is there any way to get this (forced update) status using scripting ?

The idea is to write an alias that detects it and prompt the user for actions.

Comment: `man githooks` mentions `update`, which can be used to block forced update (or similar things).

Comment: You can use the `receive.denyNonFastForwards` configuration option to *prevent* forced updates...but I'm not sure if it's possible to detect such an update from a git hook.

Comment: Thanks but I just need to detect, the action might be different than blocking.

Comment: Nov. 2018: on GitHub, this is easier now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343686/6309

Comment: @larsks that's a good hint for the server side, but the question is about client side.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have a similar problem and I figured out it.

I want to detect forced update within hook script in remote (bare) repository, So my answer might not be suitable for original question, but I hope to be useful my answer for future visitors.

---

## How to detect forced update or not from in Git hooks script

https://github.com/kyanny/git-hooks-detect-force-update

This is a sample git pre-receive hook script for learning about how to detect forced update.

### Conclusion

```
$ git rev-list oldrev ^newrev
```

### How to test

```
$ rake -T
rake forced_push  # git hooks test detect forced update
rake normal_push  # git hooks test
```

### Step-by-Step introduction

Firstly, I describe a syntax of [git-rev-list(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list).

In this case, we assume within a Git working repository that has this straight history.

```
1 --- 2 --- O --- X --- 3 --- 4 --- N
```

General usage of `git-rev-list` is below.

```
$ git rev-list N
```

This command will show all of commits reachable from commit N (note: `git-rev-list` shows commits *reverse chronological order*)

`git-rev-list` accepts multiple arguments.

```
$ git rev-list N O
```

This command will show same output as `git rev-list N`, because commit O is an ancestor of commit N.

Then, `git-rev-list` allows you to exclude commits from output.

```
$ git rev-list N ^O
```

^O means that to exclude commits reachable from O, so this command will show N, 4, 3, X (note: O is excluded)

---

Since we are learned about `git-rev-list`, I describe a case about forced update occured.

In this case, we assume within a Git working repository that has this complex history.

```
* --- B --- * --- O ($oldrev)
       \
        * --- X --- * --- N ($newrev)
```

1. In old tree, we had 4 commits (*, B, *, O) and pushed them to remote.
2. We checkout a new branch from commit B, it's new tree.
3. In new tree, we had 4 commits (*, X, *, N) and pushed them to remote with --force option!

When pushed, hook pre-receive script invoked with standard input. The format of stdin parameter is described at [githooks(5)](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

Typically, we extract two commit object sha1 from stdin - oldrev and newrev. oldrev is *HEAD of old tree*, newrev is *HEAD of new tree*.

In this situation, we can detect forced push by `git-rev-list` output.

`git rev-list oldrev ^newrev` shows the commits reachable from oldrev but not reachable from newrev. This shows the commits *existed only old tree*.
If this command show any commits, old tree was replaced with new tree, so forced update was occured. This is what we want!

If this command show none of commits, new tree was normally updated, so forced update was not occured. Simply.

### See Also

- [git-rev-list(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)
- [Git hook example: post-receive-email](http://git.gnus.org/gnus.git/hooks/post-receive-email)
- [git - How to detect a forced update - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319110/how-to-detect-a-forced-update)
- [githooks - Git hook to detect push --mirror - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210957/git-hook-to-detect-push-mirror)

Comment: Hey @kyanny , perhaps you are able to add the last 1-2 lines [missing in the update hook of this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11500008/444255)?  ( I am unsure, how to check `git rev-list oldrev ^newrev` for emptyness within a script. )

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it would be using `git reflog`, it keeps a record of the changes to the branch.

With reflog, you can get where your branch pointed before the pull/fetch (i'd use a fetch if it is scripted, since it doesn't automatically merge) and check if that commit is reachable from the new remote's "tip" of the branch.

Using bash you can try this:

```
$ git rev-list remotename/branchname | grep $(git rev-parse remotename/branchname@{1})
$ echo $?
1
```

If it returns a hash (or exit status 0) it means that it found our previous tip of the branch in the branch history, so it was a fast forward merge. If it returns nothing (or exit status 1), it was forced update.

You can check the `git reflog remotename/branchname` output to see if branchname got a forced update.

```
$ git reflog remotename/branchname
dc2afab refs/remotes/remotename/branchname@{0}: fetch rewrite: forced-update
4603c2c refs/remotes/remotename/branchname@{1}: fetch rewrite: forced-update
```

Comment: that's a good idea, let me give it a try in different scenarios

Comment: that should be working `git reflog origin/master | head -1 | grep forced-update`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git-merge-base` command, it finds nearest common ancestor for two commits.

For fast-forward update, common ancestor for `oldrev` and `newrev` must point to `oldrev`. Sample code to be put into pre-receive hook to block non fast-forward:

```
mergebase=`git merge-base $oldrev $newrev`
if [ "$oldrev" != "$mergebase" ]; then
  echo "Non fast-forward update not allowed for $refname, from ${oldrev:0:16} to ${newrev:0:16} merge base ${mergebase:0:16}"
  exit 1
fi
```