# How can I allow non-fast-foward commits on some branches but not others in a bare git repository?

Tags: git, git-bare

I have a bare git repo as my remote.  The master branch is protected from force pushes and other history changes with the following in the `config` file:

```
[receive]
        denyNonFastForwards = True
```

However, this prevents non-fast-forward updates to all branches.  This means I can't use, e.g., a rebase-style workflow in a feature branch.

Is there any way in a bare git repo to deny non-fast-forward updates to the master branch but allow them for all other branches?

Comment: See (“it should be easy enough to invert it”) https://stackoverflow.com/a/15760683/1725151

Comment: "This means I can't use, e.g., a rebase-style workflow in a feature branch." Well no, it means you can't rebase the feature branch after it has been pushed. So don't do that.

Comment: @matt "rebase a feature branch after it has been pushed" is exactly what I mean by "use a rebase-style workflow in a feature branch".

Comment: @Guildenstern thanks, it looks like that question has the answers I'm looking for.  I wasn't able to find that question on SO with my own searching.