# How to prove git commit dates are untampered with to prove innocence

Tags: git, timestamp

I'm in a tricky situation here with my uni assignment. It corrupted on upload and now I need to prove that I completed the work before the due date. I have a Git repo with all commit dates before the deadline, however I have been told this is not enough as you can change the dates of these commits.

Is there any way you can prove that these commit timestamps are legitimate?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Git commits are fully editable post-hoc.

Comment: You should really ask your TA/instructor what kind of evidence they'll accept.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100262/using-git-commit-dates-as-piece-of-evidence) not long ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question (for the future)? [How do I know if a git commit has been changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512166/how-do-i-know-if-a-git-commit-has-been-changed)

Comment: If you have at some point pushed your code to some central repository (say : on github ? or a central server hosted in your uni ?), the logs around these actions on the server side may show that commit `eacc87` already existed at that moment in time. If someone has access to this kind of proof, the hash of the commit is a strong enough proof that its *content* at that moment was the same as your own local commit `eacc87`

Comment: The question @RomainValeri linked ([How do I know if a git commit has been changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69100262/1256452)) may be a better duplicate, but I can't add it as a duplicate as it has no accepted or upvoted answer.