# git lost master branch

Tags: git, github

Hi i have a private repository here.
 https://github.com/Nuvelle/The-Last-Knights.
 i dont know what happened i was working last night and suddenly my master is showing only initial commit , committed 12 hours ago. 
there is no history and nothing.i ave been trying since morning to figure it out. any help is appreciated

[image: screenshot]

Comment: um because your repository is private I can't check it out, but are you sure you're checking the correct branch and that you've pushed your commits to GitHub?

Comment: yes i was pushing to master. i have been using master for 2 years. but now master only shows initail commit and that too created 12 hours ago. and no history and nothing else

Comment: How a question like this earns an upvote I'll never know... We have _no way_ of knowing what happened based on what you've told us. What was there before? What commands, exactly, did you run? Did you force push? Does your local `master` look like this? If not, how does it look? Please read [ask].

Comment: I'm assuming that you currently have no clone of the repository on a local machine ? This sounds bizarre a little ...

Comment: i use gitkraken gui. i did a force pull.i was trying to pull my repo on my second laptop. and i dont know what happened. if i knew what comamnds were run thn i would know myself what happend . no? and secondly i tried reflog it only shows one commit. and mater previously ha dlike 300 or so files. and i do have a clone on my other pc. but i am trying to figure out what happened and why there is no history.

Comment: @AzwarHabib Did you find back your lost commits?

Comment: git fsck --full --no-reflogs  gave me list of all lost commits. and then from there git reset -- hard [comit] restored my branch to that commit. thanks for all the help everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible explanation is a `git push --force` of a reset `master` branch.

While the local reflog might show only one commit, you might find trace of the old *remote* `master` branch state on GitHub side with the with the "poor man's reflog", aka the push events ([GitHub Events API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/)).
See "[Does github remember commit IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309)": look for any recent push events on the `master` branch: [you can then fetch that commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14872590/6309) (and its associated history) back to your local repo.
If not, the [GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) will have a look in order to restore your previous content.

The [OP Azwar Habib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9303951/azwar-habib) added [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50514697/git-lost-master-branch/50515355#comment88044517_50514697):

> `git fsck --full --no-reflogs` gave me list of all lost commits.
>   And then from there `git reset -- hard [commit]` restored my branch to that commit.

A forced push is then needed to restore the same history on the remote side.