# How to find rebase from Github API

Tags: github, github-api, git-reflog

How can we find if a pull request had a rebase operation done?

`git reflog` helps but we want to specifically discover this using Github API.

Comment: That sort of information is not kept in git and is not shared with github. You might be able to make some assumptions based on the commit tree, but they'll only be assumptions.

Comment: Some related ideas here which might help, if the rebased commit were force pushed to github: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503226/find-committer-of-a-force-push-on-github

Comment: @evolutionxbox could you elaborate what are the assumptions that can be made in what situation?

Comment: You'd need to look at the commit messages. Hopefully github adds some information about the PR in there. I'm not sure how you'd figure out whether the PR was completed with a rebase though.