# Rolling back a git commit without triggering a Jenkins build

Tags: git, version-control, jenkins

I'm in the process of setting up Git/Jenkins for a new project at work. It's the first time anyone at work has used either of these tools (currently we're using SVN and a custom build system). I've managed to get a system working; a developer does a commit, pushes to an origin/develop branch which triggers a Jenkins job using a post-receive trigger then Jenkins runs a number of testing jobs. If the tests pass, Jenkins does a push to origin/master.

This is working fine, but the problem is what happens when a build fails. A requirement is that the origin/master and origin/develop branches should be the same. So when a build fails, origin/develop should be reset to the same revision as origin/master. Again, I can do this using the following commands (this is part of another Jenkins job which is triggered on a failed build):

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard origin/master
git push -f
```

This resets the branch correctly and all is well. Except for one thing. Git sees this new push to the develop branch and triggers a new build.

So my questions is, how do I reset the develop branch to the master branch and tell Git to not trigger a build? The end goal is to reset the branch, I'm open on the mechanics. I can think of a couple of ways: add some information that the post-receive hook can pick up, however my research seems to suggest you can't pass parameters to hooks. Since there's no commit being done I can't use info from the last commit. Am I better off putting something in the triggered Jenkins build to abort if it somehow detects a rollback? Any ideas would be welcome.

One other thought. Is there a need to rollback develop at all? What happens if another push is made to origin/develop? Will it overwrite what's already there, add to it or just fail? Developers will be pulling from origin/master before making changes. The whole branching thing in Git confuses me a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Jenkins monitoring origin/development, it could monitor another branch (like `build`)

Then you can add a `post-receive` hook which would [monitor new commits on the `development` branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13057643/6309) and:

- if it [detects a forced push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12258773/6309), does nothing
- it if detects a regular push (new commits being added), it reset the `build` branch on `development` new HEAD.
  That reset will make Jenkins trigger a new build on the build branch.

If the build fails, you leave the `build` branch untouched (to not trigger anything), but you reset `development` branch as many time as you want.

The idea is to add an intermediate level of control between your developers (pushing commits) and your build (done by Jenkins)