# git commit and push not working after rebase

Tags: git, egit

I just rebased a branch against the master, then committed and pushed the end result.

This seems to work. Git status is showing

nothing to commit, working directory clean

However, when I checked the remote repository, the changed files didn't arrive. This is confusing and a little scary because my local client is saying everything is dandy (all files safely stored remotely), when it really isn't.

Any suggestions on:

- How to force the push to remote even though local git is thinking there's nothing to push?
- How to make sure the client correctly indicate the sync status?

Comment: Turns out this was due to a non fast forward error. The changes were being committed locally but not pushed remotely.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make sure the client correctly indicate the sync status?

Before pushing, you can detect if the push will be a fast forward with:

```
git rev-list origin/yourBranch ^yourBranch
```

If that returns any commit, it means yourBranch history will be replacing the one from origin, you you would have to force the push to make it happen.
See more at "[How to detect a forced update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12258773/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, the answer is NO, but it should not happen if there's something while the local git thinks there's nothing. Git keeps a remote tracking branch to track the status of remote branches. You can use "git branch -a" to find it.

```
git branch -a
```

For push after rebase, you'd better add the option "--force-with-lease". Because it's probably not a fast forward merge after rebase. And "git push" will fail with a non fast forward merge without "--force*" option. With "--force-with-lease", the push only fails if your codes are no longer latest when you do the "rebase". It makes sure that your won't overlay other guys' new commits.

```
git push origin yourBranch --force-with-lease
```

For the second question, you may check whether there're commits between your branch and the remote tracking branch with "git log", such as:

```
git log --graph --pretty=oneline origin/yourBranch..yourBranch
```