# Is it possible to check a git push --force in a GitHub action?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I want to add a condition to my GitHub Action workflow. Whenever a `git push -f` or `git push --force` is done instead of a normal `git push`. Is this possible?

Comment: sure, have you tried it? though force is kind of mute as it would be a fresh clone, why would it need forcing?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It seems you answered a different question. Do you know what GitHub Actions are?

Comment: @phd I sure do know what GitHub Actions are. I don't get your point.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I dont tried it because i dont know how? It should look something like this. `if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push --force'}}, right? I don't know the event alias to git push --force.

Comment: Maik, [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319110/how-to-detect-a-forced-update) might help you to check if a git push has been forced or not (the commands will be the same in a Github Actions workflow).

Comment: @LawrenceCherone The question is: What [`on:`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows) condition to use to trigger a workflow on a forced push? Your answer "*sure, have you tried it?*" is a rather strange answer for the question.

Comment: @phd [answers go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69882152/is-it-possible-to-check-a-git-push-force-in-a-github-action?noredirect=1#post-form), not in comments

Answer (score 6):

Not to diminish @torek's huge, detailed answer about git internals...  But the much simpler answer is that yes, you can check the `${{ github.event.forced }}` boolean in an action triggered by a push.  Conveniently, Github already does all of the hard work, and has for years.  That's how they know to add the "xxx force pushed" note in PRs. :)

The github context contains the webhook payload in the event attribure.  Docs explaining that all are below:

- https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#push
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context

Answer (score 2):

You cannot tell (anywhere, much less in a GitHub action) whether the `--force` flag was *given* to a `git push` operation.

You can, however, tell whether a proposed or accepted update *to* a reference *requires* the flag.  Whether—and if so how—you can do that *in* a *GitHub action* is a separate question; I'll provide a partial answer below, but someone who is interested in writing GitHub actions will need to take this further.

#### Core concepts at the Git level: refs and name spaces

In Git, we have *references* (or "refs").  Almost all references live in namespaces underneath `refs/`.  The *almost* weasel word here accounts for the fact that Git sometimes calls entries like `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, and so on "references"—though it sometimes calls them pseudo-refs instead—and none of them start with `refs/`.<sup>1</sup>  We don't have to worry about the pseudo-refs here and can concentrate solely on the real refs.

A ref is either *symbolic*, in which case it holds the name of another ref,<sup>2</sup> or else it holds one hash ID.  When a ref does hold a hash ID, that must be a valid hash ID for some object existing in the repository.<sup>3</sup>  Some refs should *never* change and some should move only in a *fast-forward operation*.  This brings us to the classifications of refs:

- refs that live in `refs/heads/` are *branch names;*
- refs that live in `refs/tags/` are *tag names;*
- refs that live in `refs/remotes/` are *remote-tracking names;* <sup>4</sup>
- and most others don't have any specific name.

*Branch* names must meet one extra constraint: the hash ID they store must be that of a *commit* object.  Remote-tracking names are copied from some other Git's branch names, so they too will meet this constraint.<sup>6</sup>

*Tag* names should never "move": that is, once a tag name exists and stores some hash ID, it should store that same hash ID *forever*.  This means that any request to *update* a tag name, rather than simply to create one from scratch, should be rejected unless forced.

*Branch* names should move, but only in fast-forward fashion (see below).  This means that a branch name update request should be accepted only conditionally.  *Remote-tracking* names should follow the same rules as branch names.

Other names have other purposes; in general, we don't know what constraints, if any, might be placed upon them.  You can pick one out of the list of things Git does—e.g., `refs/notes/` for `git notes`, `refs/replace/` for `git replace`, and so on—and investigate these on your own, but the above are the Big Three, and most of what we care about here.

---

<sup>1</sup>Internally, Git is gradually acquiring a real database of sorts to hold refs.  Currently they're stored very ad-hoc, as files in a file system and/or as entries in a simple text file.  The pseudo-refs are never stored in the text file and the real refs are always stored within the `refs/` directory and literally make use of the file system.  This causes problems because some file systems, e.g., the default ones on Windows and macOS, are case-insensitive, and yet Git refs are intended to be case-sensitive, and *are* case-sensitive everywhere else.  This is part of what is driving the need for the real database.  This is bringing into internal sharp focus the difference between a regular ref and a pseudo-ref; this may need to be formalized at some point.

<sup>2</sup>Generally only the `HEAD` pseudo-ref and remote-tracking names that end in `/HEAD` should be symbolic.  If you make other refs that *are* symbolic, they work ... oddly.  In the past they worked even more oddly; as progress occurs due to what's in footnote 1, this has improved, but for now, I would advise avoiding symbolic refs for normal use, except of course these standardized `HEAD` ones.

<sup>3</sup>This constraint clashes with the ideas behind *partial clones* and I can see this changing at some point.

<sup>4</sup>Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, but a *branch name* is a name you can pass to `git switch` to get "on" a branch.  A remote-tracking name is not allowed here.  So a "remote-tracking branch name" is not a "branch name".  If we were to parenthesize this, a la [diagramming a sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_diagram), we would have to be sure to consider it a ((remote tracking) branch) name, not a (remote tracking) (branch name).  Why not just drop the redundant, and otherwise heavily overused in Git, word "branch" entirely?<sup>5</sup>

<sup>5</sup>That's a rhetorical question, but the obvious answer is "stubbornness and/or obstinacy".

<sup>6</sup>It might be interesting to deliberately break a repository by forcing the wrong kind of hash ID into a branch name, and then see which Git implementations accept that wrong-kind-of-hash-ID and put it into their remote-tracking names upon running `git fetch`.  That is: who actually *enforces* this constraint?  It naturally *evolves* from branch names, but only if the other Git follows the rules.

---

#### Core concepts at the Git level: fast-forward

To understand the notion of *fast-forwarding* in Git, we must start with a quick overview of commits.  Commits, in Git, form a *Directed Acyclic Graph* or DAG.  That's because each commit:

- has a unique hash ID;
- contains the raw hash IDs of some other commits; and
- Git imposes a strong constraint on these: the hash IDs must be those of valid, existing commits at the time we create any *new* commit.

This setup means that the commits themselves are the nodes or vertices in a graph, and the list of stored hash IDs form the one-way edges or arcs connecting from each node to some other nodes.  The final constraint means that the one-way arcs always point *backwards*, to earlier nodes, which—through a simple transitive closure observation—shows us that we do in fact have an *acyclic* directed graph.

As such, given any distinct pair of node IDs N<sub>1</sub> and N<sub>2</sub>, we can ask the two questions *does N<sub>1</sub> precede N<sub>2</sub>* and *does N<sub>2</sub> precede N<sub>1</sub>*.  That is, there's a partial ordering of the graph.  Node N<sub>1</sub> precedes node N<sub>2</sub> if there is a path *through* the graph *from* N<sub>2</sub> *to* N<sub>1</sub>:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-...
```

Node `F` precedes node `H` here because we can work our way backwards from node `H` to node `G` and then from node `G` to node `F`.

(Having a N<sub>1</sub> ≺ N<sub>2</sub>, plus the obvious `H = H` and `H ≠ G`, means we can also define ≼, "precedes or equals", and inverting it gives us "does not succeed" and so on.  But note that while `F` ≺ `H` implies both `H` ≻ `F` and `F ⊀ H`—`H` succeeds `F` and `F` does not precede `H`—merely knowing that `I` ⊀ `J` does not imply `J` ≻ `I`:

```
       I
      /
...--H
      \
       J
```

Here, `I` and `J` are simply *unordered* with respect to each other.  Both succeed `H`, but we can't say that either `I` or `J` comes "first" after `H`.  [The partial order is not a total order.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/367583))

While Git doesn't provide a "succeeds or equals" test at the shell level, it does provide a "precedes or equals" test, using `git merge-base --is-ancestor` (at least [since Git 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3005392/1256452); previously you had to use a more complicated set of expressions).  Since ≼ "flips around" to ≽ and vice versa, we can test for N<sub>1</sub> ≼ N<sub>2</sub> with `git merge-base --is-ancestor N1 N2`, or test for N<sub>1</sub> ≽ N<sub>2</sub> with `git merge-base --is-ancestor N2 N1`.

**Without motivation, then, we can define "is fast forward" as "succeeds",** or perhaps as "succeeds or equals" depending on how finicky we want to be.  But let's look at motivation.

Suppose we have this graph:

```
             I--J
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L
```

where "earlier" commits are to the left and "later" commits are to the right, so that `F` ≺ `G`, `G` ≺ `H`, and so on.  As before, there's no ordering relationship from top to bottom, just from left to right.

Git *finds* commits, on a branch, by using the *branch name* to *point to* the commit that we choose to call the "last" commit on the branch.  So if name `br` points to commit `F`—contains `F`'s hash ID—then all commits up to and including `F` are "on" the branch.

If we move `F` "forward", in the direction the arrows *don't* go, one hop to `G`, commit `F` remains "on the branch".  In fact, that's probably how we made `G` in the first place: by being "on" some branch that ended at `F`, with no commits after `F` at all.  Then we made one *new* commit, and it got `G`'s hash ID, and pointed back to `F` ... and Git stored the new commit's hash ID in the branch name, so that the branch name pointed to `G`.

This pattern repeats over and over in Git, so we made `H` by being "on" a branch ending at `G` and making commit `H`, which added `H` to that branch.  But then we must have made at least one more *branch name:*

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), br1, br2
```

We then pick one of the two new names—such as `br1`—to be "on", using `git checkout` or `git switch` to move onto branch `br1`, and make a new commit:

```
             I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main, br2
```

We make another new commit `J` while "on" `br1`, then `git checkout br2` or `git switch br2` to get "on" `br2`:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main, br2 (HEAD)
```

and then make two more commits to get `K-L`:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

That's *how* we got this in the first place.

Now, if we move a branch name—such as `main`—"forward" to (say) `J`, we get this:

```
             I--J   <-- main, br1
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

All the commits that *were* on `main`—everything up through `H`—are *still on* `main`.

If we decide, now, to **force** (note key word) branch name `main` to move to `L` now, though, we get:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- main, br2 (HEAD)
```

Two commits that *were* on branch `main` have now *vanished* from `main`.  We can still find them—we still have the name `br1` for that—but they disappeared from `main`.

Let's look at our definition of "is fast forward" now: **A name motion is a fast forward if the new tip commit succeeds the old tip commit.**  So when we moved `main` to point to `J`, that was a fast-forward operation.  It *kept all the commits that were on `main`, on `main`*.  But when we moved it from here to point to commit `L`, that was a *non-fast-forward* operation.  It *dropped* commits `I-J` from `main`.

We can also move `main` in a non-fast-forward fashion by just resetting away the extra commits:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

or even by moving it back to point to commit `F`, for instance.

These are all the ways that we can move a label:

- not at all (e.g., `H` to `H`);
- to a successor commit (e.g., `H` to `J`);
- to a predecessor (e.g., `H` to `F` or `J` to `H`); or
- to an unordered commit (e.g., `J` to `L`).

The not-at-all "movement" is a degenerate case but Git will call this a "fast-forward" if asked, or at least, won't call it a "non-fast-forward".

The to-successor case is also a fast-forward, or if you don't want to count the no-movement case, is the *only* fast-forward case.

The to-predecessor and to-unordered movements are *non-fast-forward* operations.

#### Now we know what this is all about

A *fast forward* operation on a label—such as a branch name or remote-tracking name—in Git moves the label in a way such that all the commits that *were* reachable from the *old* tip are *still reachable*, from the new tip commit.

A *non-fast-forward* operation on such a label moves the name such that some commits "fall off the end".  New commits may or may not appear, as in the case where we moved `main` from `J` to `L`, but some commits *dis*-appear.

Since we generally *find* commits by starting with a label—such as a branch name—and working backwards, those movements that make commits vanish are "more dangerous".  These are our "non-fast-forwards".  Because they *are* dangerous, Git makes us use the `--force` option.

Note that you can use the `--force` option with a safe movement!  That is, a `git push` that does a *safe* branch update is itself a fast-forward operation, but you can use `git push --force` to achieve this.  It's just that you *did not have to*.

#### Applying this knowledge in certain Git hooks

Some Git hooks—specifically, pre-push, pre-receive, and post-receive—get a lot of information.  For the pre-receive and post-receive hooks, you get, on standard input, a series of lines, each of which contains three whitespace-separated strings:

- old-value (a hash ID);
- new-value (a hash ID); and
- ref-name

For the pre-receive hook, these are *proposed updates*.  The sending Git, which has been run with or without `--force`, is suggesting that you, the receiving repository, should create, update, or delete the given ref-name.

The proposed operation is a "name create" if the old-value is all-zero.<sup>7</sup>

The proposed operation is a "name delete" if the new-value is all-zero.

Otherwise, the proposed operation is a "name update".

The operation hasn't actually *happened* yet, but in your Git hook, you can inspect the new commits, if there are new commits, or the new Git objects, if there are new Git objects.  You can tell what the object's type is using `git cat-file -t` if needed, but if the name is a *branch* name, the object's type is automatically `commit` because *branch* names must point to commits: Git would have rejected this earlier otherwise.  So if the *name* has the form `refs/heads/*`, you can assume that both old and new hash IDs are commit hash IDs (well, unless one is zero, but then we're not in the update case in the first place).

This means you can now use `git merge-base --is-ancestor`.  If the proposed *new* value is a successor of the present value:

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor $old_hash $new_hash; then
    echo operation is a fast forward
```

then this is a fast-forward operation, and `--force` wasn't *required*.  We don't know if it was *used* but it was definitely not *required*.

If the proposed new value *isn't* a successor:

```
else
    echo operation must have been forced
fi
```

then we know that for us to get this far, the user must have provided the `--force` flag.

The post-receive hook is very similar.  There are two key differences between pre-receive and post-receive:

- The pre-receive hook's exit status matters: pre-receive's job is to *inspect* the requested updates and *verify that they are OK*.  Here, a Git server can do things like implement "protected branches", for instance.  (GitHub's pre-receive hooks do this and therefore you're not allowed to impose your own pre-receive hook.)

  The post-receive hook's exit status is not supposed to matter: post-receive's job is to do something like send email saying that some branch was updated.  It's already happened; it is too late to stop it.  Post-receive hooks should generally exit 0 anyway though, to avoid tripping any Git bugs.<sup>8</sup>
- At pre-receive time, the proposed update is *proposed*.  At post-receive time, it's already happened: the old-value is just what *was* stored in that name *before* the push finished.

So, while you cannot *see* the `--force` flag itself, you *can test for its effect*.  However, this is in the context of pre- and post-receive hooks, not in GitHub Actions.

---

<sup>7</sup>This removes the all-zeros hash ID from the universe of allowed hash IDs.  I'm not sure if Git ever checks to see if what comes out of its hashing function is all-zeros, but there's only a 1 out of 2<sup>160</sup> chance of this at the worst, so it probably never happens.

<sup>8</sup>The *post-checkout* hook in particular is not supposed to affect the result of `git checkout` or `git switch`.  However, if the hook exits nonzero, so does `git checkout` itself, in at least some versions of Git.  This makes other programs think the `git checkout` failed!  So make sure your post-whatever hooks exit zero, just in case there's a similar bug in an old or new version of Git.

---

#### GitHub Actions are not Git hooks

GitHub Actions are triggered *on* GitHub, *by* GitHub, on [certain events](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows).  These events include `git push`, but also include a lot more things.

Some variables are available.  The GitHub documentation doesn't seem to be all that great, because [this page](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts) mentions variables such as `github.ref`:

```
if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}
```

and then goes on to describe various "property names".  These appear to be set only in these `${{...}}` contexts (what this page seems to be about).  A [different page](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables) describes *environment variables* that are apparently available in other contexts.  It's not immediately clear to me whether there is any sensible way to access Git repository refs in the `${{...}}` section.  There are also ways to set things (property names?) in the [workflow commands](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-commands-for-github-actions).

#### What I think you would need to do

In order to do this sort of thing *in* a GitHub action, which generally runs a bit too late, you would have to:

- read the current value of a Git branch name ref, such as `refs/heads/branch`;
- compare that to the *stored* value from a *previous* run, taking care to handle the *first* run specially since there will be no such stored value;
- use the `git merge-base --is-ancestor` test to check for fast-forward vs non-fast-forward, using the stored previous hash and the current hash;
- update the stored value based on the current hash.

This would allow you to detect, not whether `--force` was *used*, but rather whether `--force` had been *required* (and thus was in fact used), in some particular `git push`.

The obvious caveats would be that this can't work until it has run at least once, to create the stored value; you must invent a reference namespace in which to store values (e.g., `refs/prevpush/$branch` where `branch` is the result of the shell expanding `${ref#refs/heads/}`, so that `refs/heads/feature/short` becomes `feature/short`); and any actions that affect refs, but bypass the GitHub action, could invalidate the stored value and lead to a misfire.

**Besides all these caveats, there's one other crucial point here for most users:** detecting that there *was* a forced-push is usually the wrong way to go about solving whatever the real problem to be solved might be.  All we get, by our careful dancing about here, is a flag: "some push must have been forced".  What we usually *really* want to know is: "what hash ID are we supposed to use?"  That question is *much easier to answer*, so if you're going down this path, make sure you're doing so for a really good reason.

Comment: GitHub does show if a commit was done using `git push --force` it says something along the lines of "user force pushed <commit-sha-1> into <commit-sha-1>" and if you want to see the 'deleted' commit it says this warning message: `This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.`